# Why isn't  immutability by default within the Domain (Business Logic) more common?

Tags: c#, immutability

I have been working with functional programming a good bit lately, and have found immutability to offer a different perspective in regard to solving problems. I am considering using immutable classes by default in my future development.

Aside from potentially a small performance cost, why aren't immutable classes more prevalent as standard convention in normal "good" design? Is there a down side I am not aware of with immutable classes (barring performance)?

I know immutability has been frequently discussed, but I had trouble finding anything specifically addressing why it's not used more than mutable classes.

Comment: because most objects are logically mutable?

Comment: And what does this have to do with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @Erix objects can be mutable or immutable. Mutability can be a perspective. Usually functional languages have everything as immutable which lends itself to some interesting benefits that I was curious about in regard to imperative programming. I don't really understand why this was closed. What isn't "constructive" about explaining the merits or detriments of mutability in an imperative domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's just because we're working on [Von Neumann model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture), which is mutable, which brings C programming languages and has huge a mount of derived languages like C++, Java, C#, etc. These languages rules the world and people have been thinking in mutable way for years. We learn mutable programming, we're taught mutable programming, most of the systems are written now are  mutable. Even people and world are mutable.

We're all (alright, most of us) mutable. We just get used to it.